# No accesstoken in populated User (Claimsprincipal)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oauth, identityserver4, identityserver3

We're using IdentityServer4 for our IdentityServer and IdentityServer3 for the client (ASP.NET MVC 5).

Everything works (the User/Claimsprincipal is set correctly through OWIN) except I cannot get the access token from the User.

We're using a implicit client which has access to these scopes: `openid, profile, testapi`

**Startup.cs:**

```
app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
{
    Authority = identityServerUrl,
    RequiredScopes = new[] { "testapi" },
});
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = "Cookies",
});
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
{
    Authority = identityServerUrl,
    ClientId = "testclient",
    Scope = "openid profile testapi",
    RedirectUri = "http://localhost:49000/signin-oidc",
    ResponseType = "id_token token",
    SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",
});
```

Code to retrieve Access Token (inside one of the controllers):

```
var user = User as ClaimsPrincipal;
var token = user.FindFirst("access_token");
```

User is set correctly, but the token is null. I am guessing it is some kind of option that I am missing in the startup.cs, but which?

Comment: I am not familiar with identity server, but at first glance to names in the code you posted (`user.FindFirst("access_token")`, more specifically `FindFirst`), it would seem that wherever location the token is pulled from might not have it - perhaps  the tokens need to be generated and that method only retrieves them?

Comment: Doesn't `FindFirst` search claims?

Comment: @zero The token is generated on the IdentityServer and should be sent to the client if I set the parameters correctly (which I think is the problem).

Comment: @john It does, yes.

Comment: @Goblin I mean, why do you expect to find `access_token` in the claims?

Comment: @john Well, it was the suggested solution for getting it in another question :) I don't really care where to get it from, I just need it. I've tried using the OwinContext to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that does exactly what I want - I'm putting it here for anyone else running into the problem. It costs a dependency on IdentityModel, but that is acceptable in my case:

In Startup.cs, I added:

```
Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
{
    AuthorizationCodeReceived = async n =>
    {
        var tokenClient = new TokenClient(identityServerUrl + "/connect/token", clientId, secret);
        var tokenResponse = await tokenClient.RequestAuthorizationCodeAsync(n.Code, n.RedirectUri);
        HttpContext.Current.Session[HttpUserContext.ACCESS_TOKEN] = tokenResponse.AccessToken;
    }
}
```

To the call to `.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication`

Answer (score 1):

I think a simpler solution is to use what is allready made availible:

```
        var options = new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Authority = authorityUrl,
            PreserveAccessToken = true,                
        };
```

Then the access token is availible as a claim (named 'token') on the User principle.

Comment: This looks promising. I'll try this out and switch the solution if I can get it to work :-)

Comment: This worked for me except that the claim property name is "token" : var token = user.FindFirst("token").Value;