# Making requests to Azure Management

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, razor-pages

I have completed the guide here to add Azure AD authentication to my application:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect-aspnetcore/

and can log in successfully, have a service principal and everything works as expected.

I now want to make web requests as the user, but can't see how to get the authentication details to send in the request, I've tried looking through the `ClaimsPrincipal.Current` object, but there is nothing i can pass to a HTTP client to make the request.

Comment: You want the access token that represents the signed in user. Have a look in this thread, which shows a couple of examples - https://stackoverflow.com/a/51061426/1538039. Once you have the access token available, you pass that on HTTP requests using Authorization: bearer {token}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample web app you refered to only signs the user in, but you need to get the access token on behalf of that user to access the api.

You can refer to this [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect-aspnetcore). This sample calls another webapi, you can ignore that part, just change the resource to `https://management.core.windows.net/`

```
    public void Configure(string name, OpenIdConnectOptions options)
    {
        options.ClientId = _azureOptions.ClientId;
        options.Authority = _azureOptions.Authority;
        options.UseTokenLifetime = true;
        options.CallbackPath = _azureOptions.CallbackPath;
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        options.ClientSecret = _azureOptions.ClientSecret;
        options.Resource = "https://management.core.windows.net/"; // management api
        options.ResponseType = "id_token code";

        // Subscribing to the OIDC events
        options.Events.OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceived;
        options.Events.OnAuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed;
    }

    private async Task OnAuthorizationCodeReceived(AuthorizationCodeReceivedContext context)
    {
        // Acquire a Token for the management API 
        string userObjectId = (context.Principal.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier"))?.Value;
        var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(context.Options.Authority, new NaiveSessionCache(userObjectId, context.HttpContext.Session));
        var credential = new ClientCredential(context.Options.ClientId, context.Options.ClientSecret);
        var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(context.Options.Resource,credential);
        // Notify the OIDC middleware that we already took care of code redemption.
        context.HandleCodeRedemption(authResult.AccessToken, context.ProtocolMessage.IdToken);
    }
```